# Failure to extend an Activity within an Android Test

Tags: java, android, testing, android-espresso

I am attempting to access a global variable within my test class.

```
    @Test
    public void checkInfo() 
{
    TM1Server mTm1Server = ((Quantum) this.getApplication()).getAdminServer().getTM1Server();
    String username = mTm1Server.getUsername();
    onView(withText("Info")).perform(click());
    onView(withText(username)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

When originially writing this code, I got the error "Cannot resolve method 'getApplication()'.  My original solution was to add "extends Activity" to my class, which allowed the test to compile, but a new error appeared:

"java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()".

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

**If anyone has this question in the future thanks to EpicPandaForce use**

```
TM1Server mTm1Server = ((Quantum) mActivityRule.getActivity().getApplication()).getAdminServer().getTM1Server();
```

**and do not extend the Activity.**

Comment: The instrumentation thread is not on a looper, so the test can't be an activity, and therefore you can't extend it like that. You should be able to use mActivityRule.getActivity().getApplication() though.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much.